# How can I find / replace text in the Description field of a HelpNDoc file?

Tags: pascalscript, helpndoc

A HelpNDoc file allows you to provide a text value for the **Description** property. This field is used by search engines when crawling the HTML help.

I have added topics to my help over the years and some of these descriptions need updating. In my case I needed to replace all instances of **Midweek Editor** with **Meeting Editor**.

How can this be done since there is no built-in way to update the Description property in bulk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by writing a script and using the [HelpNDoc API](https://www.helpndoc.com/documentation/html/HelpNDocAPImethods.html). These scripts can be built and run with the [Script Editor](https://www.helpndoc.com/documentation/html/UsingtheScriptEditor.html). The object we need to use is [`HndTopics`](https://www.helpndoc.com/documentation/html/HelpNDocAPImethods.html#HndTopics).

The `HndTopics` object includes some useful methods:

- `GetTopicDescription`
- `SetTopicDescription`

These can be used in combination with the Pascal functions `Pos` / `StringReplace`.

```pascal
var
  // Current topic ID
  aTopicId, aTopicDesc, aTopicDescNew: string;

begin
  try
    // Get first topic
    aTopicId := HndTopics.GetTopicFirst();
    // Loop through all topics
    while aTopicId <> '' do
    begin
        // Does this topic description include the phrase?
        aTopicDesc := HndTopics.GetTopicDescription(aTopicId);
        if (pos('Midweek Editor', aTopicDesc) <> 0) then
        begin
            aTopicDescNew := StringReplace(aTopicDesc, 'Midweek Editor', 'Meeting Editor', [rfReplaceAll]);
            HndTopics.SetTopicDescription(aTopicId, aTopicDescNew);
            
            Print('Old: ' + aTopicDesc);
            Print('New: ' + aTopicDescNew);
        end;
        
        // Get next topic
        aTopicId := HndTopics.GetTopicNext(aTopicId);
    end;
  finally
  end;
end.
```